# How to use Async Await in Node.js

Tags: javascript, node.js

I am new to Scraping.
This is my PDF downloading code.
I want to use Async Await in this code.
I don't know where I have to use async await in my code.

```
function scrapPdf(config, search_url, message) {
    console.log('PDF downloading');
    got(search_url).then(response => {
        const $ = cheerio.load(response.body);
        $('.search-result').find('li > a').each((idx, elem) => {
          if($(elem).text().trim() == 'PDF'){
            const item = $(elem).attr('href');
            pdf_lists.push(item);
          }
        })
        $('ul.pagination').find('li.page-item').each((idx, elem) => {
          if($(elem).attr('class').includes('page-item active navigation')){
            if($(elem).next().hasClass('page-item navigation')){
              scrapPdf(config, $(elem).next('li').find('a').attr('href'), message);
            } else {
              const search_result_dir = `./${message.date_ini}-${message.date_end}`;
              if(!fs.existsSync(search_result_dir)){
                fs.mkdirSync(search_result_dir)
              }
              for(let i = 0;i < pdf_lists.length; i++){
                const download = new DownloaderHelper(pdf_lists[i], search_result_dir);
                download.on('end', () => console.log('Download Completed'))
                download.start();
              }
              console.log(`${pdf_lists.length} files Downloaded!`);
              uploadFile(search_result_dir);
              return ;
            }
            console.log($(elem).next('li').find('a').attr('href'));
          }
        });
    }).catch(err => {
        console.log(err);
    });
}
```

Comment: Im not able to answer your question but a little hint: Async-await is overall for operations which need time to finish and during this process, you are *awaiting* the result, therefore I would suggest to look into your code and implement it for example in the place where you download the pdf.

JS cant proceed with data which is not downloaded yet, thats why you need to use async await. Its the same login like '.then()', it only proceeds if the process before is finished.

Comment: let's start with "_why_ do you want async/await in this code?" Because it sounds like you heard about something JS can do, but haven't looked at tutorials that teach how and why to use it yet, which you should _absolutely_ do before trying to put anything into your code you're not familiar with.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's one possibility assuming you only want to use `async/await` on the Promise returned from the `.then`:

```js
async function scrapPdf(config, search_url, message) {
  let response = null
  console.log('PDF downloading');
  try {
    response = await got(search_url);
  } catch (err) {
    console.log(err);
  }

  if (response) {
    const $ = cheerio.load(response.body);
    $('.search-result').find('li > a').each((idx, elem) => {
      if($(elem).text().trim() == 'PDF'){
        const item = $(elem).attr('href');
        pdf_lists.push(item);
      }
    })
    $('ul.pagination').find('li.page-item').each((idx, elem) => {
      if($(elem).attr('class').includes('page-item active navigation')){
        if($(elem).next().hasClass('page-item navigation')){
          scrapPdf(config, $(elem).next('li').find('a').attr('href'), message);
        } else {
          const search_result_dir = `./${message.date_ini}-${message.date_end}`;
          if(!fs.existsSync(search_result_dir)){
            fs.mkdirSync(search_result_dir)
          }
          for(let i = 0;i < pdf_lists.length; i++){
            const download = new DownloaderHelper(pdf_lists[i], search_result_dir);
            download.on('end', () => console.log('Download Completed'))
            download.start();
          }
          console.log(`${pdf_lists.length} files Downloaded!`);
          uploadFile(search_result_dir);
          return ;
        }
        console.log($(elem).next('li').find('a').attr('href'));
      }
    });
  }
}
```